# Generalisations of Volodin's construction of algebraic K-theory

Tags: matrices, homotopy-theory, algebraic-k-theory

In a previous [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397542/uses-of-volodins-construction-of-algebraic-k-theory) I asked about uses of Volodin's construction of the algebraic K-theory of rings. Some of these are striking and it made me wonder whether those proofs can be extended. This leads to the following question:

> Is there a way to generalise Volodin's construction to other settings, e.g. Waldhausen categories and stable $\infty$-categories?